Having a problem with async_cancel_goal with ROS2 and C++
I am writing an action with ROS2 and it should be canceled when the condition is met. I am checking that in client in feedback_callback:
void feedback_callback(
      GoalHandleRecord::SharedPtr,
      const std::shared_ptr<const OdomRecord::Feedback> feedback) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Feedback received: %f",
                feedback->current_total);

    if (feedback->current_total >= 4.5 && !is_lap_completed_) {
      if (this->goal_handle_) {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Attempting to cancel goal...");

        auto cancel_future = action_client_->async_cancel_goal(this->goal_handle_);
      }
    }}

It seems that async_cancel_goal does not work. Nothing after that is being printed or executed. goal_handle_ is defined as a class member and received as a future object from the async_send_goal, although I tried with defining it in the brackets of feedback_callback.
Other relevant parts of the code:
client:
  void result_callback(const GoalHandleRecord::WrappedResult &result) {
    this->goal_done_ = true;
    last_result_ = result; // Store the result for later access
    switch (result.code) {

...

    case rclcpp_action::ResultCode::CANCELED:
      if (result.result) {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Total odometry points2:");
        for (const auto &point : last_result_.result->list_of_odoms) {
          RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Point2(x: %f, y: %f, z: %f)",
                      point.x, point.y, point.z);
        }
      }
      RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Goal was canceled");
      break;
    }
  }

server:
 rclcpp_action::CancelResponse
  handle_cancel(const std::shared_ptr<GoalHandleRecord> goal_handle) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Received request to cancel goal");
    (void)goal_handle;
    return rclcpp_action::CancelResponse::ACCEPT;
  }

...

  void execute(const std::shared_ptr<GoalHandleRecord> goal_handle) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Executing goal");
    auto feedback = std::make_shared<OdomRecord::Feedback>();
    auto &message = feedback->current_total;
    auto result = std::make_shared<OdomRecord::Result>();

    rclcpp::Rate loop_rate(1);

    // Reset distance and initialization flag at the start of the goal
    total_distance_ = 0.0;
    is_initial_position_set_ = false;

    while (rclcpp::ok()) {
      // Check if there is a cancel request
      
      if (goal_handle->is_canceling()) {
        result->list_of_odoms = this->list_of_odoms_;
        goal_handle->canceled(result);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Goal canceled");
        return;
      }
      // Publish feedback
      message = total_distance_;
      goal_handle->publish_feedback(feedback);

      loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    if (rclcpp::ok()) {
      result->list_of_odoms = this->list_of_odoms_;
      goal_handle->succeed(result);
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Goal succeeded");
    }
  }

The code does not advance the cancel request, the cancel is not performed and the list of variables is not printed.
